# SQL Server string substring with d iterations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a string:

```
@TempCol  =  sigma_x1,sigma_x2,...,sigma_xd,XX,YY,ZZ
```

I want to get a substring to get the string `sigma_x1,sigma_x2,...,sigma_xd`.

`d` is a variable, so it can be 1, 3, 20, ..., etc.

I know the value of d, but what I don't know is how to get the substring of the original string with `d` terms.

I tried this:

```
@L = ''
SET @ColumnNo = 0
WHILE @ColumnNo <= @d
BEGIN
    SET @L  =  @L + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@TempCol, 1, CHARINDEX(',',@TempCol)-1 )
    SET @TempCol    = REPLACE  ( @TempCol,  LTRIM(RTRIM(@L) ) ,'')
    Set @ColumnNo   = @ColumnNo + 1 
    PRINT @L
END
```

but I do not know how to get the expected result.

Comment: What is `@L` initialized to and what is `L` in the first assignment to `@L`?

Comment: sorry I wrote it incorrectly it meant to be @L not L, I was trying to concatenate but not getting success. @L is initializated like @L = ''

Comment: So basically you want to extract from a string `@TempCol = 'item1,item2,...'` a substring containing first `@d` items. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TempCol varchar(max), @d int, @p int, @Result varchar(max);
SET @TempCol = 'item1,item2,itemA,itemB,item#,item$';
SET @d = 3;

SET @p = 1;

WHILE @d > 0 AND @p > 0 BEGIN
  SET @p = CHARINDEX(',', @TempCol, @p);
  IF @p > 0 SET @p = @p + 1;
  SET @d = @d - 1;
END;

IF @p = 0
  SET @Result = @TempCol
ELSE
  SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@TempCol, 1, @p - 2);

SELECT @Result;
```

Basically, the loop just searches for the final position to cut at. The substring is extracted *after* the loop.

If you specify too large `@d` then the result will simply be all of `@TempCol`, otherwise you get the desired number of items.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a split function (shown at the bottom).

```
With SplitItems As
    (
    Select Position, Value
        , Row_Number() Over ( Order By Position ) As ItemNum
    From dbo.udf_Split( @TempCol, ',' )
    )
Select Value
From SplitItems
Where ItemNum <= @d
```

If you want the assembled string up to a given point you would simply do:

```
With SplitItems As
    (
    Select Position, Value
        , Row_Number() Over ( Order By Position ) As ItemNum
    From dbo.udf_Split( @TempCol, ',' )
    )
Select ',' + Value
From SplitItems
Where ItemNum <= @d
Order By ItemNum
For Xml Path('')
```

Split function:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Split]
(   
    @DelimitedList nvarchar(max)
    , @Delimiter nvarchar(2) = ','
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
    (
    With CorrectedList As
        (
        Select Case When Left(@DelimitedList, Len(@Delimiter)) <> @Delimiter Then @Delimiter Else '' End
            + @DelimitedList
            + Case When Right(@DelimitedList, Len(@Delimiter)) <> @Delimiter Then @Delimiter Else '' End
            As List
            , Len(@Delimiter) As DelimiterLen
        )
        , Numbers As 
        (
        Select TOP( Coalesce(DataLength(@DelimitedList)/2,0) ) Row_Number() Over ( Order By c1.object_id ) As Value
        From sys.columns As c1
            Cross Join sys.columns As c2
        )
    Select CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen As Position
        , Substring (
                    CL.List
                    , CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen     
                    , CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value + 1)                           
                        - ( CharIndex(@Delimiter, CL.list, N.Value) + CL.DelimiterLen ) 
                    ) As Value
    From CorrectedList As CL
        Cross Join Numbers As N
    Where N.Value <= DataLength(CL.List) / 2
        And Substring(CL.List, N.Value, CL.DelimiterLen) = @Delimiter
    )
```

Comment: One question, As I´m using dynamic sql, how can I use this UDF in my store procedure??, I tried to call but it says there is an error??
Is there a way to use only a loop in a store procedure?

Comment: @darkcminor - Using dynamic SQL for what exactly (and why)? You would make the split UDF permanent as it can be reused often. Only the first query would need to be built or assembled.